# dotnet myprojectname.dll not working, dotnet run works - ASP.NET project deployment issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu

I am a new web developer trying to deploy my first C#/ASP.NET web application on an AWS Ubuntu server. I followed the guidelines from my coding bootcamp, which loosely follow the Microsoft documentation.

I think I have a problem related to "dotnet publish" - the symptom is that dotnet run in my main project file works, but "dotnet myprojectname.dll" is not working when I execute from the /var/www/myprojectname/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/publish" directory location. The error suggests that it can't find the views.

It gives me a long error, which includes:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLTVKGIBRRVP", Request id "0HLTVKGIBRRVP:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Dashboard' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/myprojectname/Dashboard.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Dashboard.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Dashboard.cshtml
```

I would greatly appreciate any help. Have a nice day!

Comment: what is the version of the .NET core framework ?  they changed the way it works from 2.0 to 2.1 and up.

Comment: .NET core is version 2.2. Since starting this ticket I've worked on another web app project, and it is suffering from the same problem. When I use supervisor, the views cannot be found.

Comment: I get the same or similar error

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the files you use in your project dir that are extra "assets" also inside the `Publish` folder. Those do not get moved into the folder with the dll's.  Such as the `/Views/myprojectname/Dashboard.cshtml` file..